# ADO API: Builds-List incomplete list

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm calling this API method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#response

My API url (with placeholder names):
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/MyProjName/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6

The results are mostly appropriate, except I get a filtered list of builds, and I can't seem to get all the builds I want. In particular, builds from several pipelines are simply missing, and I can't find any way to include them. There's no discernable reason why some builds are included, and some are not.

The filter options describe ways I could reduce it more, but that's not my goal. I want to retrieve builds which I am otherwise not getting. And I don't know what option that I don't know about which will get me the results I care about.

Comment: As I dig further... each of my pipelines has hundreds of builds, and Build-List has a max return of 1000.
Sooo... Maybe the filters ARE the correct answer. I need to filter my results such that I'm getting less than 1000 builds per query, or else it's truncated arbitrarily.

After a few more tests, I am getting the expected results if I filter by the specific pipeline, via "definitions=22" for example (a pipeline that was otherwise absent in the unfiltered query)

Realistically, this comment is now the answer... and I feel dumb.

Comment: Hi @PaulGilmore, Is the explanation and suggestion in my answer helpful to you? If you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noticed, there is a maximum number of the objects that can be listed on the response body of each API call. Normally, if the objects you want to list are too many, they will be returned in multiple pages.

In the response body of each call, generally there is a parameter '**`continuationToken`**' (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#uri-parameters)). You can access the next response page via calling the API with this parameter.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?continuationToken={continuationToken}&api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

For example:

- the first call returns the list in the first page;
- then run the second call with the parameter '**`continuationToken`**' returned in the response of the first call to get the second page;
- then get the third page using the '**`continuationToken`**' returned in the second response;

  . . .
- until the last page.

If you want to traverse all the pages, you may need to call the API in a loop.

Comment: Nice! I missed the continuationToken, thanks for that advice!. Your advice is 100% useful, but also I would still recommend that people making calls also use appropriate filters to try and reduce the total number of results. I personally used Pipelines-List, and then retrieved results for each pipeline one at a time.
As that set of results will likely eventually exceed 1000 as well, I think dates are the next best filter. In the end, all of the above combined is the best answer, based on the needs of the individual callers.

Comment: Yay, silent failure for everyone!